# If $A$ is clopen in $X$ then $\overline{A}$ is clopen in $\beta X$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. If $A$ is a clopen subset of $X$, then $\overline{A}$ is clopen in $\beta X$ (of course, $\overline{A}$ means the closure of $A$ in $\beta X$).

This is actually the Corollary 3.6.5 from Engelking, but he gives no proof as if it were immediately. Here is a pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqV42.png

Most likely it is related to the corollary that states every continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ has a continuous extension.

Can anyone give me a hint to show $\overline{A}$ is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Look at the continuous function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ that takes every point of $A$ to $0$ and every point of $X\setminus A$ to $1$.

Comment: Ok. That is continuous because $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are disjoint and open. It has an extension $g:\beta X\to\{0,1\}$. Clearly $A\subseteq g^{-1}(0)$ and $X\setminus A\subseteq g^{-1}(1)$. By continuity, $\overline{A}\subseteq g^{-1}(0)$ and $\overline{X\setminus A}\subseteq g^{-1}(1)$. As $\beta X=\overline{A}\cup (\overline{X\setminus A)}$ then if I'm not wrong $\overline{A}=g^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @TRmate: Looks good.